# setting custom adapter in listview is causing the screen to load for too long

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I´m developing a game for android and my activity is taking too long to load a listview with custom adapter. I already tried to pass the list to the adapter by an AsyncTask and using a progressDialog to make the user wait, but even this is making the screen(the load screen) freeze for a long time until the list components are loaded. What´s worse is that, after the screen is loaded, scrolling through the listview is too slow and can lead to the famous "Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread", which causes my Activity to, suddenly, reset. 
The listview will only have 30 components at most, but how can I make this listView not take too long to load, make it not freeze the loading screen and how can I overcome the "Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" when I load the listView?

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing the code you are trying to use.

Comment: What did you use before you introduced the custom adapter and  all went fast?